# Selenium fails on ITestListener during run time

Tags: selenium, testng, listener

I'm having a problem during run time with the ITestListener giving me the following error:

**Listener class ListenerTest must be one of ITestListener, ISuiteListener, IReporter,  IAnnotationTransformer, IMethodInterceptor or IInvokedMethodListener**

However, I have implemented the ITestListener.  This works fine when I execute via testng.xml, but not when trying to execute via a Java program (RunTestNG.java).  I've seen other posts that reference this and the solutions there do not seem to resolve my issue.  Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

```
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class RunTestNG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunTestNG rt = new RunTestNG();
        rt.testNGSuite();
    }

    public void testNGSuite() {

        RunTestNG tla = new RunTestNG();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { LoginTest.class });
        testng.addListener(ListenerTest.class);
        testng.run();

    }
}

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class ListenerTest implements ITestListener{

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to pass a class object, instead of a listener instance. What if you do `new ListenerTest()` instead of `ListenerTest.class`?

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks for your input.